# iOS: Map and list in one ViewController

Tags: ios, list, dictionary

I would like to put two different views( list and map) into one View Controller. User will be able to change view by pressing the right button on the top. For both there will be search option. If this possible, I want to separate classes for list and map.

I would be gratefull for some tip how to make it.

[views http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/1104/56044506.png](http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/1104/56044506.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you create a parent class that is a subclass of `UIViewController`, the purpose of this class will be to handle the search bar functionality and any common delegate callbacks from your datasource.

From a theory perspective this class will act as an abstract class, meaning it should only ever be subclassed rather than directly initialised, but as this is not possible to enforce in objective-c don't worry too much about that.

This next part depends on whether you'd like to use two view controllers for list and map (as at the end of the question you said you wanted to use two classes...?)

You can then either create two `UIViewControllers`, one for map and one for list, and they both will subclass the above mentioned abstract class.  This will allow them to inherit the datasource delegate callbacks and search bar functionality.

Or you can combine the two into one `UIViewController` that subclasses the above mentioned abstract class and as in *A'sa Dickens* answer, you can manage two views in a single xib file and swap between them by hiding and showing, or adding and removing them from their superview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would go with @Tim's answer and use parent/child viewcontrollers for the two views - map and list. That way you can keep the logic of the two repesentations separate. You can then inject the data for each to use from the parent and keep them in sync.

Comment: I am also speaking from previous experience as I have this exact UI design in an application I currently am working on.  Having all of the datasource, map and table view callbacks in one file with a xib file causes a very large bloated View Controller. I much prefer splitting the two into separate controllers and let them inherit common behaviour

Comment: Ok, so I will create one parent class ( subclass of UIViewController) with data, and two child classes for mapView and listView. But how to make the rest in Storyboard file - there will be only two UIViewControllers for child classes? Sorry , but I'm a newbie and It's hard for me without seeing any example project :)

Comment: You want to manage your MapView and ListView within a container, if you look at the iOS container programming guide this will explain an approach.  The MapView and ListView will both inherit their data from the parent. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: Thank You! "Container View Controllers" That's the key :)

Answer (score 0):

with in your xib or storyboard have 2 views 1 for the map view and 1 for the list view, when ever they click one of the buttons it hides one of the views and reveals the other with the hidden property

```
[listView setHidden:NO];
```

that's an example ....

make sure you have a reference to both views, and that the reference is linked. That is an obscure way to do it. you could also try a tab view controller... but that is more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Use a UITableView and a MKMapView and add them to the same content view.
Use the hidden property to hide and unhide the views depending on the button clicked by the user.