# Map & List Views (Yelp style)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, listview, dictionary

In order to make interchangeable map/list views (map with pin annotations and table view with the same data) and then have the pins and list view cells lead to the same detail view controller based on pin or cell clicked, should I save JSON data to the list view and then loop through that data to plot on a map? (I currently have them plotted using MKPinAnnotationView)

Or is there a way to auto-fill a list view with the data from map annotations (based on map region, user location)?

Also, I can do a modal segue (flip horizontal) to switch between the views, but I don't know how to just flip the view underneath the UINavigation bar. I tried searching, but all of the results gave me answers for flipping iPhone orientation (vertical-->horizontal) which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interested in this also, but don't have a solution yet.

There could be a solution using a Container View with two views.

This also seemed relevant to consider:
[iOS: Map and list in one ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262106/ios-map-and-list-in-one-viewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up putting the map and list in the same view controller, grabbing the JSON data twice. I definitely think having a container view with the data would be better.